# Mixed literal and array parameter type in class with generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class like this

```
class Schema<T extends "foo" | string[]> {
  constructor(public value: T) {}
}
```

for which the constructor should accept the string literal "foo" or an arbitrary array of strings. An instantiation should return an object which is typed with only the literals (also for the array as union literals):

```
// What I would like to have
new Schema(["x", "y"]) // => Schema<"x" | "y">
new Schema("foo") // => Schema<"foo">
```

This is not the case for the above class implementation (it returns an object of type `Schema<string[]>` when providing an array).

But if I define my class this way

```
class Schema<T extends "foo" | string> {
  constructor(public value: T[]) {}
}
```

I lose the option to call `new Schema("foo")`.

Is there some Typescript KungFu to solve this problem?

Comment: How is the generic used elsewhere in the class? I'd keep having, eg, `Schema<["x", "y"]>`, but transform it into the desired type (union?) when needed later

Comment: If type `string` represents the set of all possible strings then `"foo"` is "covered" by `string`. `"foo" | string` represents exactly the same set as `string`. So, `"foo" | string` is equivalent to just `string`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance The real class is of course much more complicated and it is important that the type gets inferred by the parameter.

Comment: @spender Yes, I know. And that's why I use `"foo" | string[]` in my first class example, but this doesn't infer the union type correctly. But I guess it is not possible with just one parameter.

Comment: I don't think changing the type parameter for the whole class conditionally like that is possible. But I can't think of a situation, even in a complicated class, where such a transformation would be *essential*. Creating the union from the array in all the methods where it's needed would be WET if it's used in multiple places, but would work, I'd think. (But I might be wrong, feel free to edit to show how that wouldn't work)

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMMjrm) works for you and if not - why?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Yes that's nice, but the first instance has the type `Schema<string, ["x", "y"]>` and not `Schema<string, "x" | "y">` which would be better. But I guess `Values` can be mapped to a union later on when needed (maybe by `Values[number]`. Do you like to provide an official answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have most simpliest way:

```js
class Schema<Value extends string, Values extends string[]> {

  constructor(value: Value | [...Values]) { }
}

// What I would like to have
new Schema(["x", "y"]) // Schema<string, ["x", "y"]>
new Schema("foo") // Schema<"foo", string[]>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NlvyBW)

As you have already noticed, there is a problem with extra `string` or `string[]` generic.

I think we can do better.

SInce `constructor` does not allow us to use generics, we can create extra `method` for inference purpose.

```js
class Schema {
  register<Value extends string>(value: Value): asserts this is { value: Value }
  register<Value extends string[]>(value: [...Value]): asserts this is { value: Value[number] }
  register<Value extends string | string[]>(value: Value): asserts this is { value: Value } {


  }
}

const result: Schema = new Schema();
result.value // expected error
result.register(['x', 'y']);
result.value // x | y
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRRPnw)

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) you can find docs about `asserts` and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) about function overloads.

Please let me know if it works for you and if it needs to be improved. THank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer and nice explanation!